# Android emulator for Windows?

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, emulation

I don't have administrative rights on computers that I use. How I can run an Android OS on Windows XP or 7?

Comment: This is not a programming question. See superuser.com or android.stackexchange.com Though you could use the android emulator, but to get any performance out of it you would need the intel accelerated images and driver and you can't do that (driver) without admin rights.

Comment: Try http://www.bluestacks.com/app-player.html

Comment: @KenWolf, the installer terminates.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it requires admin rights. Worth a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Eclipse installed it comes with an in-built Android emulator. You can also launch it from command-line. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) for the command-line use guide (list of useful commands to be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)). As for Eclipse [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) is probably the best place to look for guidance as to how to set it up.

Comment: I have downloaded http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html only "SDK Tools Only": android-sdk_r22.0.1-windows.zip I far as remember now, adn it works.